# What do I hear when I hear a diesel car running?

Tags: acoustics

Diesel engines in cars are notoriously loud. When I hear one, it feels like I can hear it rotating, it sounds a bit like the way I would pronounce a “rolling r”.

Today it struck me: the RRRRRRRRRRRR I’m hearing is at a rate that is several orders of magnitude below the thousands of RPM at which the engine is turning.

So this makes me wonder: what am I hearing that gives me this impression?

Comment: This does not seem like a physics question.

Comment: The tick-over rate for a Diesel engine in a car is about 600 rpm, that is 10 per second. But the engines are 4-stroke, implying that certain operations  (e.g. exhaust valve opening) occur only once every two cycles, that is 5 times a second on tick-over. Perhaps the discrepancy is not as huge as you thought. [You might get a fuller answer in the Engineering Stack Exchange.]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There was a recent video, [Simulating an Entire Car Engine (yes, it makes noise)](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=RKT-sKtR970), which might provide some nice context.

Answer (score 1):

Every time a cylinder fires in a diesel engine, it produces a sudden violent shock to the cylinder head and the engine block because the combustion of the fuel and air mixture is itself a sudden, violent *detonation* (unlike the smoother *deflagration* of the fuel-air mix in a gasoline-powered engine).

This violent shock is called "knock" and in a diesel engine running at idle, you can hear the sharp explosions as knocketa-knocketa-knocketa, as if someone were banging a hammer against the engine block. This is particularly apparent in four-cylinder diesels where the power strokes of the individual cylinders do not overlap, and you hence hear the individual knocks separated slightly in time.

As the engine speeds up, the knocketas blend into a smoother but still distinctive  diesel B-R-R-R-R-R-R-R-R-R-R sound that then becomes BRRRRRRRRR at higher speeds.